# App that shows root words and other words derived from that root

Tags: android, educational, language, dictionary

English is not my native language and my vocabulary is really poor. I'm currently taking [Building a Better Vocabulary](http://www.thegreatcourses.com/courses/building-a-better-vocabulary.html) course. Professor, in that course, introduced a wonderful method for learning vocabulary: finding the root word(s) and then learning all words derived from those root words(s) at once. I love this method for improving vocabulary.

My problem is I don't like using internet search for finding roots and words derived from them. It is time consuming. Is there an Android app, preferably the one that works offline, which gives root words and other derivatives of those roots, along with the meanings of words?

I really like interface of wordweb app but unfortunately it doesn't have the feature I need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is an App that meets 100% of your criteria (Android platform, gives root words and other derivatives of those roots, gives definitions, and works offline), but have a look at the following Android Apps that closely match your criteria:

- [Painless Roots](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phucnguyen.education.vocab.roots&hl=en)
- [GRE Flash Cards: Root Words](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fuf.roots&hl=en)
- [GRE Vocabulary Root/Etymology](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.djingool.gremaster&hl=en)
- [Word Learner Vocab Builder GRE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wordLearner.Free)